# what iam policies are requried to run ecr commands on ec2 instance that has assumed a role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform, amazon-ecr, amazon-ecr-public

I have a small jenkins instance that uses terraform to deploy some stuff such as ECR
When trying to apply changes i get this error

```
error creating ECR Public repository: AccessDeniedException: 
User: arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/jenkins_role/i-1234567890 is not authorized to perform: ecr-public:CreateRepository on resource: arn:aws:ecr-public::1234567890:repository/test-repo
```

[image]

I would have thought `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess`  would be enough but that was not the case. When I added `AdministratorAccess`, it worked. So why is that the case?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you are missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` applies **only to private ECR**. You are trying to use `ecr-public`. This means you have to create your own policy which allows `ecr-public:CreateRepository` (not `ecr:CreateRepository`).

Comment: @TheSuperDoughnut No problem. Glad it worked out:-)